# Rebuild request header from HTTP proxy server to Remote Server in C

Tags: c, http, proxy, get

I need to develop an HTTP proxy server. My proxy server is able to retrieve the HTTP request from web brownser. And I also able to connect to the server. I am not able to understand how to move further:
It how send the request to the Remote Server from proxy server.
I have following queries:

1. **The format of request header to be send from HTTP proxy server to Remote Server**
2. **Is it the same header I received from the web brownser for GET,HEAD and POST methods.**

I have tried sending the entire header:
GET http://www.gmail.com/ HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive
Host: www.gmail.com

Or:
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host:www.gmail.com:80

Comment: I have tried sending the received from HTTP request header                Sending   GET path HTTP/1.version\r\nHost:www.gmail.com:80\r\n

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The fundamental transformation you need to do from a proxy request to an HTTP server request is to change the first line:

```
GET http://www.gmail.com/ HTTP/1.1
```

to

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
```

The full URL is required when the browser sends the request to the proxy, so that the proxy can make the further connection to the real server. However, an HTTP request to the server must *not* contain the protocol and hostname parts on the `GET` line.

However, this may not be the only thing you need to do. An HTTP proxy is a fairly complex application, due to things like different protocol version numbers and connection options on the browser-proxy connection versus the proxy-server connection.

[RFC 2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) contains a considerable amount of information regarding the correct behaviour of HTTP proxy applications.

Comment: SO it should be something like this:                              GET / HTTP/1.1
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)  
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate  
Proxy-Connection: Keep-Alive  
Host: www.gmail.com

Comment: I guess so, I can't see where your line breaks are in the comment. But you'll also want to act upon that `Proxy-Connection` header, as that is sent by the browser to the proxy and is not intended to be passed on to the server. Again, read RFC 2616 for full details.

Comment: I am able to connect to the server,  but the problem is that proxy server is not reading entire response from the server. Connection is being reset by remote server while proxy is receiving data. Is the problem in reading data with this code while((n = read(rfd, buff, MAXLINE)) > 0) {
  write(connfd, buff, MAXLINE);
  printf("%s",buff);
   bzero(buff,MAXLINE);
  }